# insert or update

Tags: android, sqlite, sql

Есть табличка, с данными. Необходимо составить запрос на добавление N-го кол-ва записей, при этом если запись с таким именем (name) уже существует, то вместо добавления, необходимо  изменить одно из его полей (допустим count). Я сам в sql не силен, могу только простенькие запросики писать. Помогите составить пожалуйста.

П.С.: Своих умений хватило только на insert, а вот как туда остальное впилить не знаю:

```
insert into (name, count, ...)
select 'пряник', 4,...
union select 'плюшка', 5,...
union select 'баранка', 3,...
(и так все N)
```

П.П.С.: Докопался до триггеров:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON products
 BEGIN
  UPDATE OR IGNORE uniqueItems SET amount=new.amount WHERE name = new.name;
 END;
```

Теперь добавление продукта, который уже существует, апдейтит старую запись, но и добавляет новую. Как этого избежать?
Пробовал изменить само поле:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE, amount INTEGER);
```

Но в результате триггер игнорируется и таблица остается без изменений.

Comment: хм, а как в мускуле не выйдет там? 

    insert into my_tbl values(id,data,....) on duplicate key update set data=data+1;

Comment: к сожалению нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого предназначен оператор [MERGE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), но я не уверен, что его поддерживает sqlite.

```
Тогда могу предложить такой алгоритм:
 1. создаете таблицу для новых данных.
 3. Берете пересечение этой таблицы с существующей - эти строки обновляете.
 2. Берете разность этой таблицы с существующей - эти строки вставляете.
```

Comment: такого оператора нет.

Comment: Значит вам придется реализовать его доступными средствами sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

не знаю, как в SQLite, но в MS SQL можно сделать вот что:

```
IF (какое-то условие)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE <table_name>
    SET       <поле> = 'что-то там'         
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  <table_name> (<какие-то столбцы > )
    VALUES    (   <какие-то вставляемые значения>   ) 
END
```

Вполне возможно, что и в вашей СУБД есть что-то вроде IF

Comment: если это кусок процедуры или функции, то в sqlite это сомнительно
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite насколько я понимаю речь именно об андроид, там Sqlite.

Comment: Да речь идет об Android и  Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

читаем  [тут](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)   и [тут](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)   и выбираем для себя путь.

По сути  как я понял 2 пути

1. вам нада настроить таблицу - тоесть выделить уникальное поле (поля, связка полей) определить их командами  указать что делать при конфликте вставки.
2. или  при запросе использовать не INSERT а INSER OR REPLACE - тут тупо на сколько я понял если встречаются строки создавшие конфликт по уникальности или первичному ключу, то новые строки втавляются а строки вызвавшие конфликт удаляеются

путь 2 проще - но на сколько я понял более затратный.

может быть и не прав- не судите строго

Comment: Как я понимаю insert or replace, если встречает похожую строку, то удаляет ее и записывает новую. Это не подходит, т.к. потеряются данные из исходной строки.
Попробую пойти по первому пути и покурить маны